# GPL version not specified, and actual license text not provided with the source

Tags: gpl

I'm working on porting a very old program (1994) that was released under the GPL. However, the only reference to that license is this text in the header of the C files:

> This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation.  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 675 Mass Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139, USA.

Should I then assume that it's version 1, and can I release it under a later version of the GPL?

Comment: Initially, I would assume yes. The GPL should let you relicense under any later version of the licence.

Comment: Thanks. If I don't get a more authoritative answer than that, I'll move forward under that assumption.

Comment: Don't take my word on that yet though. Though I will see if I can find something along those lines.

Comment: If you don't or can't, I'll move forward under my assumption, not yours. ;)

Comment: No, you can not. It was (presumably) licensed *only* under GPLv1. Unless the "or, a your option, any later..." wording is present, it does not apply. In any case, GPLv1 is from 1990 (or somewhat earlier, it evolved from previous licences for emacs), GPLv2 were published in June 1991. *If* the code was written in 1994, I'd suppose it is GPLv2 *only* (see the wording...), but the fact that no version is mentioned would point at GPLv1.

Comment: @lordcheeto In fact, do you know where I can find the old program (or at least the name of it or something like that)?

Comment: @Zizouz212 I didn't think it had anything else useful, but of course. http://hint.byu.edu/pub/HINT/source/serial/unix/

Comment: @lordcheeto Oh my... That looks... well.... scarily old.

Comment: @vonbrand I would think that in that case, using either GPL v1 or v2, if there is no [looking up GPL text] nevermind, the license actually makes it clear. Answering the question.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Yeah, it's going to take some work to get it to modern standards, but the concept behind the program is still sound, and I haven't found anything like it published more recently. Anyways, thanks for your help. Answer has been posted below.

Comment: Yep! And it deserves a +1 (I knew there was something like that :) ). I wish you luck on your project!

Comment: The tarball contains sources dated from 1998, the README is from 1994. Strangely, the head comment on the files shows some understanding of copyright issues and licensing, credits some official-sounding organization, cites the GPL, but botches it's application inexcusably. Any contact for the Iowa State University Research Foundation, Inc.? Perhaps this is a mutilated version of something Iowa State University published?

Comment: This seems to be (some preliminary version of?) the work leading to Rajat Kumar Todi's 2003 [PhD thesis](http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2912&context=rtd)

Comment: It was developed by [Dr. John L. Gustafson](http://johngustafson.net/hint.html) and others at the Ames Laboratory, with research papers indicating it was developed as early as 1994. No idea how it was originally released, or if it was, before being tarballed in 1998. I'll need to take a look at that dissertation, but at first glance, it seems to only have dead links.

Answer (score 13):

From the [text of the license](https://gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-1.0.txt):

> If the Program does not specify a version number of
>   the license, you may choose any version ever published by the Free Software
>   Foundation.

This clause is in every version of the GPL.