# Can an Apache 2-licensed work be derived from a GPLv1-licensed work?

Tags: gpl, apache-2.0

The [Apache Software Foundation page on GPL compatibility](https://www.apache.org/licenses/GPL-compatibility.html) says that
Neither GPLv2 nor GPLv3 can be incorporated into an Apache 2 project.

It doesn't directly make a statement about GPLv1.
But in does make a indirect statement:

> Despite our best efforts, the FSF has never considered the Apache License to be compatible with GPL version 2, citing the patent termination and indemnification provisions as **restrictions not present in the older GPL license**.

(emphasis mine)

Am I correct then in my understanding then that GPLv1 is compatible, as it does not the restrictions that were added in GPLv2?

Comment: This came up when I was looking into: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5612/what-are-the-requirements-of-the-crayon-license-for-the-penn-tree-bank-tokenizer?noredirect=1#comment14241_5612

Answer (score 8, accepted):

License compatibility is a one-way street, so we ought to phrase statements about license compatibility very precisely: So for two licenses X and Y, we are interested if “X-licensed code can be used in Y-licensed software”.

### Can I use GPL-licensed code in Apache-licensed software?

For all versions of the GPL and the Apache License: GPL-licensed code cannot be used in Apache-licensed projects. This is because the GPL is a *copyleft license* that requires the resulting work to be published under the same license as the original work. So it is impossible to base an Apache licensed work on a GPL-licensed work (any version). For the GPLv1, this is clear from [section 2.b)](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-1.0.en.html):

> 2. You may [distribute modifications], provided that you also do the following:
>
>    […]
>
>    b) cause [any work that partially or completely contains the Program] to be licensed […] under the terms of this General Public License […].

So you cannot take GPLv1 code, modify it, and publish the modified version under any different license.

### Can I use Apache-licensed code in GPL-licensed software?

The other direction is a bit more differentiated. Because the Apache licenses are *permissive licenses*, they can be used with any other license that satisfies the terms of the Apache license. However, the Apache License 2 contains a patent license that complicates things. That is what your quote is about: according to the FSF, Apache-2-licensed code cannot be used in GPLv2-licensed projects. If it were possible to use Apache-2 code under the GPLv2, that would “forget” about the Apache-2 license's patent terms which is not possible. With the GPLv3 this point has been made compatible by adding relevant terms, so you can use Apache-2-licensed code in a GPLv3-licensed project.

To be clear about the understanding of the quote: it talks about the “patent termination and indemnification provisions” of the Apache-2 license, and “the older GPL license” refers to the GPLv2. So you can't use Apache-2-licensed code because the GPLv2 does not contain equivalent terms to the Apache 2 license. It makes no statement about the GPLv1. The patent terms were not added in the GPLv2, but in the GPLv3 and the Apache 2 license.